# Как обратиться к элементам, функциям родительского окна?

Tags: winforms, .net, c++

Здравствуйте!

Есть два окна: Form1(parent), Form2(child);
Не получается получить доступ к переменной\функции  родительского окнуа.
Вот код:

```
  //Main:
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    #include "Form2.h"
    #include "Form3.h"
    #include "Form1.h" 
    using namespace Server_WFA;

    [STAThreadAttribute]

    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {
            // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
            Application::EnableVisualStyles();
            Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
            // Create the main window and run it
            Application::Run(gcnew Form1());

        return 0;
    }

//Form1:

#pragma once

namespace Server_WFA {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public: 
void opener(){}
        Form1()
        {       
            InitializeComponent();
            opener();
            form2 = gcnew Form2(this);

        }

        Form2^ form2;
    ....

//Form2:

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Server_WFA {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form2
    /// </summary>
    ref class Form1;//Дообьявляем!

    public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    private: Form1^ owner;
    public: 
        Form2(Form1^ own)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            owner = own;
            this->Owner->Name=L"";//opener();
            this->Text=owner->label1->Text;
                    owner->opener(); // ничего не работает!!!
        }
```

Некоторые ошибки:

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'Server_WFA::Form1'
> error C2227: left of '->opener' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Как обратиться к функции opener? находящейся в `form1`?

Comment: Может у кого исходники есть с двумя окошками, которые могут обращаться друг к другу?

Comment: Может есть. VladD дал хороший ответ, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том что не работает...
Вот код: Form2.cpp
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Form2.h"

namespace Server_WFA {//Использую пространство первой формы

 using namespace System;
 ...

void Form2::InitializeComponent(void)
  {..

Ошибки:
1>Server_WFA.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) Server_WFA.Form2::.ctor
1>Form2.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000008) Server_WFA.Form2::.ctor
1>Form1.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000008) Server_WFA.Form2::.ctor
1>...\Server_WFA - копия\Debug\Server_WFA.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

Comment: Что не так с этими окнами? Где можно про это прочитать? Искал что-то подобное-не нашел, учат создавать окно, а как к родительскому обращаться не учат...

Comment: Всё, всё работает!!! Спасибо VladD!!!

Comment: @Alerr: отлично, видите, там не всё так ужасно было. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы пишете на WinForms, переходите на C#, там проблем с ручным управлением видимостью нету.

Во-вторых, C++/CLI -- это язык, основанный на C++, и наследующий его необычные особенности. В вашем случае, forward-объявления

```
ref class Form1;
```

недостаточно. Вам нужно разбить классы на декларации (которые уходят в `.h`) и имплементации (которые уходят в `.cpp`), и подключать декларации, где нужно, как обычно в C++.

Пример:

```
// Form1.h
ref class Form2; // достаточно forward-декларации

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public: 
    void opener();

    Form1();

private:
    Form2^ form2;
....
};

// Form1.cpp
// forward-декларации недостаточно, нужен доступ к функциям
#include "Form2.h"

...
void Form1::opener()
{
    // ...
}

Form1::Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    opener();
    form2 = gcnew Form2(this);
}
```

Comment: А вот как быть с срр? Где их подключать? К срр с main? На сколько я понял вас:
1) Нужно конструкции классов держать в .h, а соответствующии им функции прописывать в cpp, в том числе и функции событий. Правильно? А почему так странно?

Comment: @Alerr: .cpp нигде подключать не надо, просто пусть будут в проекте. По поводу такого разделения -- ну, в нём когда-то была своя логика, а теперь оно существует для обратной совместимости. Считайте это странностью языка C++.

Comment: Сделал, добавил функции в срр, получил ошибки вида 
error C2653: 'Form1' : is not a class or namespace name
1>Form1.cpp(11): error C2653: 'MessageBox' : is not a class or namespace name. Похоже нет к этим элементам доступа...

Comment: @Alerr: а вы `#include` в начале .cpp не забыли? namespace добавили?

Comment: Исправился:

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Form2.h"

namespace Server_WFA {

 using namespace System;
 using namespace System::ComponentModel;
 using namespace System::Collections;
 using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
 using namespace System::Data;
 using namespace System::Drawing;

void Form1::opener()
{}....
Куча ошибок, например ругается на конструктор... Деструктор оставил в классе...
 error C2653: 'Form1' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: @Alerr: не забудьте ещё `#include "Form1.h"`!

Comment: Дело вроде движется... Добавил Form1.h, теперь ругается на конструктор form2 = gcnew Form2(); 
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Server_WFA::Form2 ^' to 'Form2 ^'

Comment: Места для коментариев закончилось, пишу сюда...  А аналогичные действия нужно совершать над классом второй формы? Не с этим связана ошибка  form2 = gcnew Form2(); error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Server_WFA::Form2 ^' to 'Form2 ^'?

Comment: @Alerr: значит, вы  делаете forward-декларацию Form2 не внутри namespace Server_WFA. А надо внутри.

---
Да, аналогично надо со второй формой.

---
А не забыли ли вы namespace в Form2.h?