# Как добраться до полей класса-формы?

Tags: winforms, c++

Добрый вечер!

Помогите разобраться с самым нелепым и глупым вопросом: у меня есть формы, родительская и дочерние, все они могут взаимодействовать между собой....

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Form3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

//================================

#define MAX_CLIENTS 64
int Count=0;

namespace PA {

bool testing(){//not form1 member
    ???????->richTextBox1->Text=""; //Не получается изменить или обратиться к переменной Form1
    return 0;
}

void Form1::trdMethod(){
testing();
}

void Form1::Form1(){}

}
```

Есть функция которая может обратиться к глобальным переменным(Count) в cpp файле... **А как из нее добраться до какой-нибудь переменной обьявленной в классе родительского окна???** Уже сколько провозился, и безрезультатно(

Comment: Много неполных формулировок. Покажите код.

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

К non-static членам можно обращаться только через экземпляр класса. Передавайте `this` в функцию `testing()`.

Вероятно, вам будет полезно прочитать ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193280/winforms-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: А асли обращаться к статическим? Меня ставит в тупик отсутствие обьекта класса главной формы(! Как бы обьекта нет, но форма существует....

Comment: @Alerr, я же написал, передавайте `this` из `Form1:trdMethod()` в свою функцию.

Comment: Эта функция как-бы не моя. Вообщем в нее нельзя ничего передавать...

Comment: Тогда что в этом коде ваше?

Comment: Ну, если нельзя никак получить доступ к объекту формы, нельзя и получить доступ к его полям. Ищите, как получить доступ к форме, без этого никак.