# Доступ к элементам формы из другого класса

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть форма `Form1` с элементом `label` и подключенный файл AnotherClass.h.

Как из класса `AnotherClass` получить доступ к элементу `label1`, который находится, по сути, в другом классе.

Из метода `SetTextToLabel`, который находится в классе `AnotherClass`:

```
#pragma once
#include "AnotherClass.h"

namespace TestProject {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    ///
    /// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
    ///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
    ///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
    ///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
    ///          resources associated with this form.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->anotherClass = gcnew AnotherClass();
            this->anotherClass->SetTextToLabel("AAA");
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: AnotherClass^ anotherClass;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 13);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"label1";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

И вот класс, в котором происходят все действия:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"

namespace TestProject {

    using namespace System;

    public ref class AnotherClass {
    public:
        AnotherClass(void) {

        }
    protected:
        ~AnotherClass(void) {

        }
    public:
        void SetTextToLabel(System::String^ text) {

            // Здесь происходят какие то действия, после чего нужно для label1 заменить текст.
            // Это тестовый проект для примера проблемы.
            // На реальном проекте этот метод запускается не из файла Form1.h,
            // а запускается сам по событию
            // Пробовал TestProject::Form1^ form1 = gcnew Form1();
            // появляется ошибка 'Form1' : is not a member of 'TestProject'
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Любопытно, так как неожиданно для меня, почему вы занимаетесь C++/CLI? Это по работе или по учебе?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: По учёбе, думаю. Задали написать программу с графикой, но на C++.

Comment: Кто-нибудь, найдите дубликат. Вопросов о том, как двум классам помириться между собой, в контексте именно C++/CLI + Winforms, было примерно миллион.

Comment: Нужно для себя, изучаю подключение всякой электроники к компьютеру. На C++ удается запрограммировать USB реле, купюроприемник, и т.д. Пробовал смотреть подобные вопросы, но все же не удалось получить доступ к элементам формы из другого класса.

Comment: Мне нужно узнать хотя бы способ обращения к нестатическим методам Form1 из другого класса. Предположим в классе Form1 есть метод SetLabelText, который задает текст для label. Так как этот метод сам находится в классе Form1, то уже не будет проблемы получить из него доступ к label. Но вопрос, как обратиться к этому методу из другого класса?

Comment: По вашим рассуждениям видно, что вы пытаетесь осмыслить проблему с позиции *процедурного* программирования, но при этом вы имеете дело с объектно-ориентированным кодом, поэтому решение от вас ускользает.
Похоже вы мыслите класс, как простой модуль содержащий функции, на деле все несколько сложнее. Если вы хотите работать с объектно ориентированным кодом, вам надо ознакомиться с основами ООП, узнать что такое класс и что такое объект, в чем между ними разница.

Comment: Чтобы AnotherClass мог работать c методами вашей формы, он должен иметь ссылку на нее. Вы создаете экземпляр AnotherClass в форме вот так `this->anotherClass = gcnew AnotherClass();`. Вам надо передать в конструктор класса ссылку на вашу форму, примерно вот так  `this->anotherClass = gcnew AnotherClass(this);`. Потом в конструкторе вам надо записать полученную ссылку в приватное поле с именем, скажем `form`. Используя это поле, вы сможете получить доступ к методам формы, сможете написать вот так  `form->SetLabelText("AAA")`. Это в общих чертах, я не работал c С++, думаю там могут быть нюансы.

Comment: Кажется нюансы описаны в ответе к [этому](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193280/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0) вопросу.